# React native: How to Kill the old screen when navigate to a new screen using BottomTabNavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

When I navigate from the current screen to another. The requests of the old screen keeps running. So,
I need to cancel and kill any request or anything running in background when I navigate to a new tab in my application. In other words I need to destroy last screen. How to do this if I'm using 'BottomTabNavigator' ?

Comment: can you show the code that runs these requests?

Comment: Are you trying to change from bottom tab to another tab? Or are you trying to go to another stack?

If you go to another stack instead of use `navigation.navigate()` try to use `navigation.replace()` that will replace the current stack to the other one, and this action will 'kill' your current stack.